# Cannot apply physical font to an AWT Button in Java applet run under Windows

Tags: java, windows, fonts

I am writing an applet using a "physical font", that I embedded in the jar file as follows:

```
javac Test.java
jar -cf Test.jar Test.class *.ttf
```

The compilation gives no error and the font is in the same directory as the source and is successfully embedded in the resulting jar.

The font is LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf

Here is the code of a near-minimal example Test.java

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test extends Applet {
    Font font;

    public Test() {
        try {
            InputStream f;
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            f=classLoader.getResourceAsStream("LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf");
            font=Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,f).deriveFont(15.0f);
            System.out.println(ge.registerFont(font));
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("oops");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Button b=new Button("Am I serifed ?");
        add(b);
        b.setFont(font);
    }
}
```

Here is the file Go.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<APPLET CODE = "Test.class" ARCHIVE="Test.jar" WIDTH = 400 HEIGHT=200>
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I copy Go.html and Test.jar to a new directory, I cd to that directory, then I run

```
appletViewer Go.html
```

It outputs in the console:

```
true
ok
```

*but* the button in the applet has the default font instead of the one I shipped (it has the right size 13pt, though).

Tested on Windows 7 using java 1.7.0_25

Permuting add(b); and b.setFont(font); did not help.

I also tested the resulting code by putting it on my website and browsing it from a Mac and a PC with Firefox : it worked on the mac, but not the pc! Firefox has the same Java plugin version on both machines: 1.7.0_25. Neither the mac nor the pc has this font installed in its OS.

If I ask the applet to draw a string in the paint(Graphics g) function, with the physical font, it works! (in the three tests!) So the applet has the font. It even works *without* registering the font with ge.registerFont(font).

I tried to add other buttons with logical fonts in the applet: it works. But logical fonts, though they have system independent names, turn out to have system dependent shape and size, so this is not what I want.

My guess is that I forgot some operation, but which?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Interesting problem, what about calling b.setFont(font); before you call add(b); (thinking a rendering issue)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem using the Button class. I couldnt get any fonts working with the Button class either. However I did get the JButton class to take to the font no problem.

```
JButton b=new JButton("Am I serifed ?");
```

My guess is AWT doesnt have much font support due to is swings popularity in the fancy UI area.

If you dont know about swing....swing and AWT are 2 different ways to acheive a java interface, they are used and accessed the same and in many cases interchangeable. Eg: you can use your swing JButton inside your AWT Applet (Swing has a JApplet)

Heres an article covering pros and cons of swing vs AWT http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26970

Comment: Thanks. I started with Swing in fact. It was 15 years ago. It was ideal because more platform independent than AWT. But then the applets would not run in browsers, so I switched to AWT and sticked to it ever since.